# apply javascript to multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html

I Have JavaScript/HTML code like this:

```js
const priceDiv = document.querySelector('#pprices');
priceDiv.textContent = (+priceDiv.textContent).toLocaleString('en-US');
```

```html
<div id="pprices">125135135</div>
<div id="pprices">1361436136</div>
<div id="pprices">136136136136</div>
```

The problem is that the JavaScript Code affects the first div only.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can't have multiple "unique" identifiers, aka ID.

Comment: ```document.querySelector()``` return only first element

Comment: Because IDs should be UNIQUE!

Answer (score 4):

1. IDs should be unique. Use `class` instead.
2. `querySelector` returns the first matching element. Use `querySelectorAll` instead.
3. `querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList object so use the `forEach` method to loop through the list.

```js
const priceDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.pprices');
priceDiv.forEach(e => {
    e.textContent = (+e.textContent).toLocaleString('en-US');
})
```

```html
<div class="pprices">125135135</div>
<div class="pprices">1361436136</div>
<div class="pprices">136136136136</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `querySelectorAll` with class instead of ids and `forEach` for pass all elements

```js
const priceDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.pprices');
priceDivs.forEach(function (priceDiv) {
            priceDiv.textContent = (+priceDiv.textContent).toLocaleString('en-US');
        });
```

```html
<div class="pprices">125135135</div>
<div class="pprices">1361436136</div>
<div class="pprices">136136136136</div>
```